# CHOOSECOLOR undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi, visual-c++

I'm creating a win32 project and for some weird reason Visual studio doesn't recognize the CHOOSECOLOR function. I keep getting the " choosecolor' :undeclared identifier" error. what do I do??

my current code that causing the error.

```
void cColor(HWND hwnd, int select)
{
CHOOSECOLOR cc; //common dialog box structure




}
```

any help on how i can resolve this problem, would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You haven't posted enough code for us to identify the problem. There isn't even a line here with `choosecolor` in it (the comment doesn't count, since the compiler ignores it). Can you post a short self-contained piece of code that, when copy-pasted and compiled, gives the same error you're seeing?

Comment: sorry I forgot to uncomment the CHOOSECOLOR. If you copy the my current code and paste it into a new win32 c++ project right underneath the #include statement and compile it. you get the error.

Comment: what Kevin is saying is basically what is written over at [sscce.org](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Well, what is the "CHOOSECOLOR" function?

Comment: the Choosecolor function is used to intialize the colour dialog box in windows.

Answer (score 4):

The `CHOOSECOLOR` structure is defined in `Commdlg.h`, which is automatically included when you include `Windows.h`. You can find this on [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646830%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) by looking toward the bottom of the page where it says "Header".

Often `Windows.h` will be included in `stdafx.h`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I got all the right headers. dunno why it wont compiler.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is VERY old. However I had the same problem and found the solution so for future seekers: make sure that you don't

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
```

it makes that it doesn't include rarely-used stuff, including CHOOSECOLOR.